# Error initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types] when trying to read and write to proc

Tags: pointers, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I have been trying to implement the read and  write methods of the file_operations struct. Below are the declarations of my methods

```
ssize_t Ccom_file_read_proc(char *buf, char **start, off_t offset, int count, int *eof, void *data);
ssize_t Ccom_file_write_proc(struct file *file, const char *buf, unsigned long count, void *data);
```

Here is where i fed them to my file operations struct

```
static struct file_operations proc_fops = {
    .read = Ccom_file_read_proc,
    .write = Ccom_file_write_proc
};
```

Here is where i called my proc_dir_entry

```
proc_create(raw_file_data.file_name,0,0, &proc_fops);
```

This is the error that i get

```
error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
.read = Ccom_file_read_proc,
```

I tried to change the type of my read and write functions to static int but i still receive the same.

Comment: The `read` member of `struct file_operations` is defined as `ssize_t (*read) (struct file *, char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);` That does not at all match your `Ccom_file_read_proc` prototype. Hence `incompatible-pointer-types`.